# String to float with two decimal place in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, decimal

Is this correct way to convert string to float with two decimal places?

```
    string s1 = "9.09"; 
    string s2=  "99,09";
    string s3=  ",09";

    ConvertToFloat(s1);  
    ConvertToFloat(s2);
    ConvertToFloat(s3);

    private float ConvertToFloat(string value)
    {
        float result;
        decimal de= Convert.ToDecimal(value);
        bool IsDecimalFormat = IsDecimal(de);
        if (IsDecimalFormat)
        {
            result =Convert.ToSingle(value);
        }
        else
        {
            result = Convert.ToSingle(value)/100;
        }
        return result;
        }
    }

    private bool  IsDecimal(decimal myDec)
    {
        return (Decimal.Ceiling(myDec) > myDec) ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: You've got a mixture of "." and "," in your sample data. Do you want both to be treated as decimal points? Fundamentally this is a very confusing function, sometimes returning 1/100th of the value. Also, if you're interested in decimal places you should almost certainly be using `decimal` everywhere rather than `float`.

Comment: I assume `/100` is meant to support internationalization - `"99,09"` -> 9909 -> 99.09. I'm pretty sure it fails for the input `"99"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want decimal places, the correct way is to return a `decimal`. A `float` does not *have* decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd code `ConvertToFloat`:

```
private float ConvertToFloat(string value) {
    if (!Validate(value))
        throw new ArgumentException (value);

    string[] v = value.Split(new char[] {'.', ','});
    int integer = 0;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(v[0])) {
        integer = Convert.ToInt32(v[0]);
    }
    int dec = Convert.ToInt32(v[1]);
    return integer + (dec / 100.0f);
}
```

**EDIT**

I Added the validation method.

```
public static bool Validate(string a)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(a, @"^\d*[\.,]\d{2}$");
}
```

Comment: What if the input was `1,000.5`?

Comment: This is the conversion code, validating the string is `IsDecimal`'s task. Anyway, it's easy to create a regexp that checks it.

Answer (score 0):

As John pointed out, if you have  "." and "," in your sample data, then you might consider using `decimal.Parse(value, CultureInfo.xxx` with the allowed cultures.